# Tagging content in one channel for other channels

Tags: relationships, multiselect

We have a channel of article content (called 'Articles'), and each of those entries is categorized as either a 'standard, case study or bulletin.'

I have 3 other channels, and I want to select when an entry in the 'Articles' channel is posted, which other channel it's also relevant to.

So for example, I post a "Latest Study" entry to the 'Articles' channel, and want to indicate that it's also relevant to channel 2 and 3. This way it can auto-populate the other channels.  If categories were not already used, I would likely have done it that way.

Can I do this with relationships? I haven't used the new relationships from 2.6 very much. I tried setting it up but it was going the wrong way (pulling content from the other channels into the 'articles' channel, rather than the other way around).

Basically what I am saying, I want to dictate from the pool of articles in one channel, what's relevant to other channels... other than using categories.

Any help would be appreciated. I have a feeling it's something obvious I am not considering.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're reason for not wanting to use categories is because they're already used, you can have multiple category group in a channel group. So, Category Group 1 could be whatever is being used now and then Category Group 2 could be used to associate it with some other channel. I'm doing something similar on a recent project.

Shift-clicking, I believe, is the keyboard combo to select mulitple category groups in the Channel > Category Group list.

Comment: LOL Wow! I can't believe I didn't know that! Just what I needed.